# ImageMagick error: -contrast option replaced with -level (huh?)

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a simple ImageMagick command that uses `-contrast` which is well-documented here: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#contrast

My command:
`magick in.jpg -enhance -contrast -background white -quality 100 -resize 200x200^ -gravity center -extent 200x200 out.jpg`

But I'm getting this error: **magick: option has been replaced '-contrast', use "-level" at CLI arg 3 @ warning/operation.c/CLISimpleOperatorImage/2078.**

I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2019-12-02.

```
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

So... **why is it complaining about the `-contrast` option?** It looks like `-contrast` is still there, and I don't see how `-level` is supposed to replace it. There's nothing I can find about `-contrast` being replaced/removed. It's very strange.

** UPDATE - even I can see [right here](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickWand/operation.c#L2078) in the code where that error message is generated. However, I can't see why it's doing that, and as I said, can't find anything in any documentation that implies `-contrast` should not be used.

Comment: I get the same message on IM 7.0.9.7 Q16 Mac OSX. But there is nothing in the porting documentation about that. I think it is a bug. But as an alternate, you can use -brightness-contrast bri,con. It is more flexible as you can specify the amount of brightness and/or contrast.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah, I think it's a bug too. I'll look at substituting -brightness-contrast.